# Prepending instead of appending NaNs in pandas using from_dict

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that I am reading from a `defaultdict` in Python, but some of the columns have different lengths.  Here is what the data might look like:

```
Date      col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
01-01-15  5       12      1      -15      10
01-02-15  7       0       9       11      7
01-03-15          6       1       2       18
01-04-15          9       8       10
01-05-15         -4               7
01-06-15         -11             -1
01-07-15          6
```

And I am able to pad the blanks with `NaN`s like so:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(pred_dict, orient='index').T
```

Which gives:

```
Date      col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
01-01-15  5       12      1      -15      10
01-02-15  7       0       9       11      7
01-03-15  NaN     6       1       2       18
01-04-15  NaN     9       8       10      NaN
01-05-15  NaN    -4       NaN     7       NaN
01-06-15  NaN    -11      NaN    -1       NaN
01-07-15  NaN     6       NaN     NaN     NaN
```

However, what I'm really looking for is a way to prepend `NaN`s instead of appending them to the end, so that the data looks like this:

```
Date      col1    col2    col3    col4    col5
01-01-15  NaN     12      NaN     NaN     NaN
01-02-15  NaN     0       NaN    -15      NaN
01-03-15  NaN     6       NaN     11      NaN
01-04-15  NaN     9       1       2       NaN
01-05-15  NaN    -4       9       10      10
01-06-15  5      -11      1       7       7
01-07-15  7       6       8      -1       18
```

Is there an easy way to do this?

You can recreate the dictionary with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d["Date"].extend([
    "01-01-15", 
    "01-02-15", 
    "01-03-15", 
    "01-04-15", 
    "01-05-15",
    "01-06-15",
    "01-07-15"
])
d["col1"].extend([5, 7])
d["col2"].extend([12, 0, 6, 9, -4, -11, 6])
d["col3"].extend([1, 9, 1, 8])
d["col4"].extend([-15, 11, 2, 10, 7, -1])
d["col5"].extend([10, 7, 18])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little modification on the itertools solution to your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38446457/2285236):

```
pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.zip_longest(*[reversed(i) for i in d.values()]))[::-1], columns=d.keys()).sort_index(axis=1)
Out[143]: 
       Date  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
0  01-01-15   NaN    12   NaN   NaN   NaN
1  01-02-15   NaN     0   NaN -15.0   NaN
2  01-03-15   NaN     6   NaN  11.0   NaN
3  01-04-15   NaN     9   1.0   2.0   NaN
4  01-05-15   NaN    -4   9.0  10.0  10.0
5  01-06-15   5.0   -11   1.0   7.0   7.0
6  01-07-15   7.0     6   8.0  -1.0  18.0
```

Comment: I like this one +1

Comment: Yeah, hard to read but this one gets the job done.  Was hoping for an answer closer to the one I accepted, but it doesn't look like that will be the case.

Comment: I myself didn't like it very much actually. Don't know how many times iterating over that dictionary.  :)

Comment: If I am still using python 2, would `izip_longest` still work here?

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) to induce the  Series/DataFrame. Unfortunately you can't pass in array of periods - you must shift each column by an integer value.

```
s = df.isnull().sum()
for col, periods in s.iteritems():
    df[col] = df[col].shift(periods)
```

Answer (score 2):

Reverse every list in the dictionary:

```
for k, v in d.iteritems():
    d[k] = v[::-1]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T.set_index('Date').sort_index(1).sort_index().astype(float)
```

[image]

Comment: Why do the dtypes become object with this one?

Comment: No idea!  Interesting.

Comment: @ayhan `df = df.astype(float)` fixes that right up.  Maybe trying to preserve the `int`?

Comment: I think it is because of the date (before taking the transpose it is a part of every row). I wonder why set_index doesn't have an axis parameter. It would be easier to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vectorized approach that uses [`pd.DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) to get the dataframe for the usual case. Once we have a regular `2D` data available, it becomes easy enough to flip and mask and get to our desired output dataframe in a vectorized manner.

The implementation is listed below -

```
# Get the normal case output
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T

# Use masking to flip and select flipped elements to re-create expected df
colmask = df.columns!='Date'
arr = np.array(df.ix[:,colmask].values, dtype=np.float).T
mask = ~np.isnan(arr)
out_arr = np.full(mask.shape,np.nan)
out_arr[mask[:,::-1]] = arr[mask]
df.ix[:,colmask] = out_arr.T
```

Sample run -

```
In [209]: d.values()
Out[209]: 
[[-15, 11, 2, 10, 7, -1],
 [10, 7, 18],
 [12, 0, 6, 9, -4, -11, 6],
 [1, 9, 1, 8],
 [5, 7],
 ['01-01-15',
  '01-02-15',
  '01-03-15',
  '01-04-15',
  '01-05-15',
  '01-06-15',
  '01-07-15']]

In [210]: df
Out[210]: 
  col4 col5 col2 col3 col1      Date
0  NaN  NaN   12  NaN  NaN  01-01-15
1  -15  NaN    0  NaN  NaN  01-02-15
2   11  NaN    6  NaN  NaN  01-03-15
3    2  NaN    9    1  NaN  01-04-15
4   10   10   -4    9  NaN  01-05-15
5    7    7  -11    1    5  01-06-15
6   -1   18    6    8    7  01-07-15
```