# Pandas dataframe from dictionary of list values

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary with lists as values such as:

```
cols = {'animals':['dog','cat','fish'],
        'colors':['red','black','blue','dog']}
```

I want to convert this into a dataframe in which each of the lists are enumerated according to their key with the result of

```
key variable
animals dog
animals cat
animal fish
colors red
colors black
colors blue
colors dog
```

SO far, I have done this: but it does not provide me with desired result.

```
cols_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cols, orient='index')
```

How can I modify this to achieve the above?

Comment: You want long-form but `from_dict(.. orient='index')` only gives wide-form and  `from_dict(.. orient='columns')` fails with `ValueError('arrays must all be same length')`

Answer (score 10):

No imports, works on all inputs:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame([(key, var) for (key, L) in cols.items() for var in L], 
                 columns=['key', 'variable'])

       key variable
0  animals      dog
1  animals      cat
2  animals     fish
3   colors      red
4   colors    black
5   colors     blue
6   colors      dog
```

Answer (score 4):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cols, orient='index').T.unstack().dropna().reset_index(level=1,drop=True)

animals      dog
animals      cat
animals     fish
colors       red
colors     black
colors      blue
colors       dog
```

where we first need to pad cols to equal lengths to prevent `from_dict(.. orient='columns')` failing. Two ways to do that:

1. `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cols, orient='index').T` is an undocumented trick I found in [this answer by root](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38446637/202229); `transpose` adds NaN cells to make the result rectangular
2. The manual alternative is find how many cells you need to pad each row, something like:

   Compute the pad amount with `df_cols.apply(pd.Series.pad, max(len(c) for c in cols.values()))
   ...
   cols['animals'].append(np.NaN)`

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the fastest solution and you need additional lists.

```
d = {'animals': ['dog','cat','fish'],
     'colors': ['red','black','blue','dog']}

keys = [k for k in d.keys() for v in d[k]]
values = [v for k in d.keys() for v in d[k]]
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'index': keys, 'values': values})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cols, orient='index')
df = df.stack().to_frame().reset_index().drop('level_1', axis=1)
df.columns = ['key', 'variable']

df

key variable
0   colors  red
1   colors  black
2   colors  blue
3   colors  dog
4   animals dog
5   animals cat
6   animals fish
```

**DEMO:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(cols, orient='index')
df

        0   1      2    3
colors  red black  blue dog
animals dog cat    fish None
```

`df.stack()` returns a series. That needs to be converted to a dataframe using `to_frame()`. A `reset_index()` is done afterwards to get the desired frame.

```
df.stack().to_frame().reset_index()


 level_0 level_1 0
0   colors  0   red
1   colors  1   black
2   colors  2   blue
3   colors  3   dog
4   animals 0   dog
5   animals 1   cat
6   animals 2   fish
```

Now `drop('level_1', axis=1)` and set the column names get the expected frame.

Answer (score 0):

Using `itertools.chain` and `itertools.repeat`:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import chain, repeat

chainer = chain.from_iterable

d = {'animals': ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'],
     'colors': ['red', 'black', 'blue', 'dog']}

df = pd.DataFrame({'key': list(chainer(repeat(k, len(v)) for k, v in d.items())),
                   'variable': list(chainer(d.values()))})

print(df)

       key variable
0  animals      dog
1  animals      cat
2  animals     fish
3   colors      red
4   colors    black
5   colors     blue
6   colors      dog
```

Answer (score 0):

use itertools crossproduct to create a key / value paired dictionary that can be loaded into a dataframe

```
 import itertools

 cols = {'animals':['dog','cat','fish'],
    'colors':['red','black','blue','dog']}

 keys=cols.keys()
 values=cols.values()

 data=[]
 for key,values in cols.items():
     results=itertools.product([key],values)
     for key,item in enumerate(results):
          data.append(item)

 df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['category','value'])
 print(df)
```

output:

```
  category  value
0  animals    dog
1  animals    cat
2  animals   fish
3   colors    red
4   colors  black
5   colors   blue
6   colors    dog
```