# Convert a muti-valued dict into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, append

I want to convert this dict into a pandas dataframe where each key becomes a column and values in the list become the rows:

my_dict:

```
{'Last updated': ['2021-05-18T15:24:19.000Z', '2021-05-18T15:24:19.000Z'],
 'Symbol': ['BTC', 'BNB', 'XRP', 'ADA', 'BUSD'],
 'Name': ['Bitcoin', 'Binance Coin', 'XRP', 'Cardano', 'Binance USD'],
 'Rank': [1, 3, 7, 4, 25],
}
```

The lists in my_dict can also have some missing values, which should appear as NaNs in dataframe.
This is how I'm currently  trying to append it into my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Last updated',
                                            'Symbol',
                                            'Name',
                                            'Rank',]
df = df.append(my_dict, ignore_index=True)
   
                    
#print(df)
df.to_excel(r'\walletframe.xlsx', index = False, header = True)
```

But my output only has a single row containing all the values.

Comment: 'Last updated' key only has 2 values but other have 5 each. So how do you want to handle the missing 3 values for 'Last updated'?  Add NaNs there?

Comment: Actually, 'Last updated' has 5 values aswell, but I found another key that has only 1 value, how do I add the remaining values as NaNs?

Comment: Check if the accepted answer in this post solves your problem:  [Filling dict with NA values to allow conversion to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446457/filling-dict-with-na-values-to-allow-conversion-to-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Yes, it works flawlessly now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was pretty simple, instead of using

```
df = df.append(my_dict)
```

I used

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(my_dict).T
```

Which transposes the dataframe so it doesn't has any missing values for columns.

Credits to @Ank who helped me find the solution!

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to accept your answer, so that others can benefit from it :)